# Docker login credentials, pass + gpg

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gnupg, archlinux

I have a fresh install of Arch with `docker` and `docker-compose` installed via pacman.

Every time I try to `docker compose up -d`, I get an error

```
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `exit status 2: gpg: public key decryption failed: No such file or directory
gpg: decryption failed: No such file or directory`
```

This is after setting up `docker-credential-pass`, and running `docker login -u myuser`. I followed a process similar to [this](https://steinbaugh.com/posts/docker-credential-pass.html), if that helps.

Additionally, the credential helper doesn't provide the password to the `docker login -u myuser` command.

I tried to regenerate the gpg key and reinitialize pass, but nothing changed. I've reinstalled docker and reset the configs, but to no avail.

The docker.service daemon is running, `docker login` works, but with a manually provided password. Some images even pull down from docker hub, just not this `wordpress:php8.1` image.

EDIT:
So I was able to pull the image directly via `docker image pull wordpress:php8.1`. Then `docker compose up -d` works. Based on this I'm wondering if there's a difference between auth with `docker` vs `docker-compose`?